# Null Type filtering on nested Crystal object

Tags: crystal-lang

I get an

```
undefined method 'start_time' for Nil (compile-time type is (Reservation | Nil))
```

for the code

```
 if game.reservation && other_game.reservation
       if(game.reservation.start_time == other_game.reservation.start_time)                    
            return false 
       end
 end
```

But if I do this

```
reservation : Reservation | Nil = game.reservation
other_reservation : Reservation | Nil = other_game.reservation
if reservation && other_reservation
    if(reservation.start_time == other_reservation.start_time)                    
        return false 
    end
end
```

Why aren't these expressions equivalent? Normally, the if is a type filter that removes the `Nil` union from the type, but not when it is a nested object. The second way works, but feels needlessly verbose.

**What's the right way to perform a type filter with an if on a nested object?**

Comment: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/if_var.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify this a bit (it's still the same error):

```
if game.reservation
  game.reservation.starting_time
end
```

The conditional ensures that the return value from `game.reservation` is not `nil`. This expression is just calling the method `reservation` on `game`. The returned value is not reused after that and there is no way of knowing if the second call to that same method might return `nil`.

You can solve this easily by storing the return value in a local variable. This way the compiler can be sure that it's value is not `nil`. This is even more performant because it saves an (potentially costly) additional call to the same method.

```
if reservation = game.reservation
  reservation.starting_time
end
```

The exact behaviour is explained in more detail in the language reference: https://crystal-lang.org/docs/syntax_and_semantics/if_var.html